# How to try something until available object is found

Tags: java

The title is probably a bit confusing, but I don't really know how to explain this. I have a list of objects, in this case, locations, and those locations can be occupied by a player. If the selected location is already occupied, how can I try to find a new location, and continue this until non-occupied location is found?

I already know that there are 20 locations, I could manually check each and every one of those locations and see if it's occupied, but is there a better way to do this?

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
List<Location> spawnList = arena.getManager().getRandomSpawns(); // Returns a list of possible locations
Location random = spawnList.get(new Random().nextInt(spawnList.size())); // Selects a random location from the list

if (random.isOccupied()) {
    /* Location is occupied, find another one from the list, and continue doing this until non-occupied location is found */
}
```

Sorry if you didn't understand, I don't know a good way of explaining this.

Comment: what is the size of spawnList. Is it too big to loop over?

Comment: 20 locations is not a big number to iterate over. Do u really need to make this more efficient?

Comment: @jazz11 In this case no, but I wanted to know if there is a way to do this if I ever need to do something similar in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Location> spawnList = arena.getManager().getRandomSpawns();
Location random;
Random r = new Random();

do {
  random = spawnList.get(r.nextInt(spawnList.size()))
} while(random.isOccupied());
```

This will fail if **all** locations are occupied, you should check this before.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of two ways:

1. Push - when a location becomes available , notify that it is now available. (By calling a method, for example).
2. Polling: Something like you are doing now. It is possible to hold a collection of available locations, when a location becomes available it is added to the collection. you can wait for the list to have values. I would suggest [A blockig queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a flag to check if candidate Location is found, and using while - loop to generate random Location, like,

```
    Location random = null;

boolean foundLocation = false;
while(!foundLocation)
{
    random = spawnList.get(new Random().nextInt(spawnList.size()));
    if(!random.isOccupied())
    {
        foundLocation = true;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Here has a assumption that there is at least one Location in the Location List, which is not occupied. If all of the Locations are occupied. Then the above code can not be used. It will be in infinite loop. We'd better check if at least one Location is not occupied in the List first.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial approach would be to randomize a location in a loop until one is found:

```
List<Location> spawnList = arena.getManager().getRandomSpawns(); // Returns a list of possible locations
Location random = spawnList.get(new Random().nextInt(spawnList.size())); // Selects a random location from the list

while (random.isOccupied()) {
    random = spawnList.get(new Random().nextInt(spawnList.size()));
}
```

The problem here is that this may take a very long time if most of the locations are already occupied.

A "safer" approach, which promises the same order of performance regardless of the percentage of pre-occupied locations could be to shuffle the list of locations, and then simply iterate through it:

```
List<Location> spawnList = new LinkedList<Location>(arena.getManager().getRandomSpawns());
Location random = null;

for (Location loc : spawnList) {
    if (!loc.isOccupied()) {
        random = loc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stochastically probing until you hit an empty spot, you should

1. first collect all available locations and then
2. pick a random free location.

```
List<Integer> freeLocations = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < spawnList.size(); i++)
  if (!spawnList.get(i).isOccupied) freeLocations.add(i);

Location random = 
   spawnList.get(freeLocations.get(rnd.nextInt(freeLocations.size()));
```